# Как применить математическое определение функции к функциям CSS?

Tags: css, css3, html5

В математике функция это зависимость одной переменной от другой, а в CSS тогда это зависимость чего от чего? В CSS же есть функции (например calc(), linear-gradient () и т.д.)?

Comment: Зависимость результата от аргументов )

Comment: Тогда почему значения, например width,  height, нельзя назвать функциями? Здесь же тоже зависимость результата от аргументов. Какое значение задашь (аргумент) , такой и будет высота/ширина (результат).

Comment: Я ж поставил полусмайлик. Скажу так - нет причин связывать значение слова "функция" в программировании с таковым в математике. У слова "функция" имеются разные значения в русском языке: "Какова функция этой детали в механизме?", например, и математика тут не при чем.

Comment: А как же тогда быть с функциональным программированием, которое как раз стремится повторять математические концепции? =)

Answer (score 2):

Сначала немного вооружимся теорией(в упрощенном виде, см комментарии):

В математике функция - это отображение элементов из одного множества на элементы другого множества по некому соответствию (иногда такие множества называют `доменом` и `кодоменом` соответственно. Для краткости, в дальнейшем будем использовать именно эти понятия).

Например мы можем взять некий `x` из домена, допустим двойка из множества целых чисел, и сопоставить для него некий `y` из множества строк - `"два"` или `"2"`, смотря каким именно образом мы устанавливаем соответствие.

Элементом домена не обязательно должно быть простое значение(как например двойка), это может быть пара `(a,b)`, тройка `(a,b,c)` и так далее. Но это все еще один элемент домена, просто, "составной"(своими словами).

Пример: мы можем отобразить все(почти) элементы множества пар целых чисел на множество дробных чисел, используя деление первого аргумента на второй. Схематично проиллюстрирую это:

```
      Домен                             Кодомен
╔═══════════════╗              ╔═══════════════════════╗ 
║     (5,2) ----║--------------║--------> 2.5          ║
║               ║              ║                       ║
║     (8,2)-----║--------------║--------> 4.0          ║
║               ║              ║                       ║
║     (10,3)----║--------------║-> 3,33333(бесконечно) ║ 
╚═══════════════╝              ╚═══════════════════════╝
```

Тут представлены лишь некоторые элементы множеств. на самом деле сами множества вполне могут быть бесконечными. А могут и не быть.

---

Теперь зная это посмотрим на `calc`. Пример:

```
calc(80% / 6)
```

Домен этой функции присутствует в выражении неявно, он спрятан за сахар, но он все равно присутствует. Это - множество ширин документа. Говоря математическим языком, функция отобразит каждую текущую ширину документа на определенное значение. Можно читать так: `80 процентов от текущей ширины экрана разделить на шесть`.

Точно так же `linear-gradient`:

```
linear-gradient(0.25turn, #3f87a6, #ebf8e1, #f69d3c);
```

Только тут домен состоит не из простого значения, а из "составного"(опять своими словами). Однако соответствие с элементами кодомена все равно будет установлено.

---

> Тогда почему значения, например width, height, нельзя назвать
>   функциями?

Опять таки говоря математическим языком, `width` и `height` не отображают одни значения на другие(домен на кодомен). Они используют уже готовые значения(заданные явно, или из кодоменов различных функций(вычисленные)).

Это просто свойства какого-то элемента на странице, скорее как аргументы некоторой внутренней в браузере функции, которая отрисовывает некоторый очередной `div`.

Comment: Ну нет. Домен calc - это множество арифметических выражений. А область значений - как раз названное вами множество функций из R в R.

Comment: @PavelMayorov Арифметическое выражение, если в него подставить все значения всегда(опять почти) редуцируется до конкретного значения. Например `someFunc(3 + 2 - 1) -> someFunc(4)`

Comment: Или я неправильно Вас понял

Comment: Это только до тех пор, пока вы под 3 + 2 понимаете число 5, а не символьную запись последовательности операций. Во втором случае редукция - тоже функция.

Comment: @PavelMayorov Кажется я понял. `calc` в моем примере это безусловно ФВП. Действительно, ее домен составляет множество других отображений, доменом каждого их которых и является то самое множество текущих ширин экрана. В ответе я намеренно убежал от этой сложности, опустив этот промежуточный этап, который конечно же очень важен для теории, но на мой взгляд только помешает в контексте ответа на конкретно этот вопрос. Ответ отредактировал, добавив ремарку о том, что представленная теория несколько упрощена относительно реального положения дел.

Comment: А в linear-gradient что является кодоменом? Цветные пиксели?

Comment: @Since Вероятно некий внутренний объект, который браузер способен отобразить как градиент.